# Removing specific objects from an array in corona lua

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to randomly spawn objects which move toward a ball that can be dragged around the screen. Basically I just want the user to try to avoid these objects. I am trying to make the arrows spawn and move toward the balls location and then despawn after a time. This code here works fine for the first arrow but when it tries to delete the second one it calls and error saying `attempt to call method 'remove self' (a nil value)`.

```
local function cleararray()
    if ( object[objectTag] ) then
        object[objectTag]:removeSelf()
    end
end

local function spawnObject()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    local objIdx = mRandom(#objects)
    local objName = objects[objIdx]
    object[objectTag]  = display.newImage("btn_arrow.png") 
    object[objectTag].x = mRandom(320)
    object[objectTag].y = mRandom(480)
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    print(objectTag)
    transition.to( object[objectTag], { time=2000, y=myObject.y, x=myObject.x } )
    timer.performWithDelay(2000,cleararray,1)
end
```

Comment: Attempt to call method `remove self`? Are you sure you don't mean `removeSelf`? There is a difference.

Comment: Your `cleararray` function is using the global objectTag which is always the id of the last object you have created. That's not going to work correctly. You need to have `cleararray` operate on the objectTag of the object you are timing out.

Answer (score 0):

`cleararray`  meeds some way of knowing which object you want to remove. Referencing the `objectTag` won't work, because that's global, so it's always going have the highest value you've reached thus far, rather than the value of the object you're trying to remove. Instead, you can create a closure that references the object, so it knows what object to operate on.

```
local function spawnObject()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    ...
    local function cleararray()
        object[object.name]:removeSelf()
        object[object.name] = nil
    end
    timer.performWithDelay(2000,cleararray,1)
end
```